# How would you find the formula for the following numbers in a list?

Tags: probability

```
177 (starting number, i don't know the previous numbers)

188 + 12 (188 + 12 = 200 and so forth)

200 + 12

212 + 12

224 + 13

237 + 13

250 + 13

263 + 14

277 + 14

291 + 15

306 + 15

321 + 15

336 + 15

351 + 16

367 + 16

383 + 17

400 + 17

417 + 17

434 + 18

452 + 18

470 + 18

488 + 19

507 + 19

526 + 19

545 + 20

565 + 20

585 + 20

605 + 21

626 + 21

647 + 22

669 + 22

691 + 22

713 + 22

735 + 23

758 + 23

781 + 24

805 + 24

829 + 24

853 + 25

878 + 25

903 + 25

928 + 26

954 (ending number, I do not know the next numbers)
```

I've been trying to figure out the formula to these numbers, but without success. Wondering if anyone could give it an attempt to figure it out?

I want to be able to predict the coming numbers, after 954. This is hard.

Comment: Why is it $224+12$ then? Is it $+13$ instead?

Comment: Correct. Updated the question.

Comment: If any simple pattern is likely, it's "3324233". The second cycle was just completed at 25. So you'll want +26 3 times, +27 3 times, +28 2 times etc.

Comment: @DavidPeterson is there a formula to use for this though?